# How can I become "Fanatic" and earn gold medal on superuser.com cheating?

Tags: discussion

I would like to get a gold medal on superuser but I'm not very constant so I often forget to login and my day count goes again to zero.
I have servers working 365 days so I look for a good idea to reload the site opened and make my way to golden badge without effort.
Any hints?

Comment: -1 Python > mechanize

Comment: What kind of reason is it to downvote? O_O

Comment: I didn't downvote, but *really*? You ask how you can cheat for a badge? Also, if the only badge you have in sight is the one for logging in each day, well, enough said.

Comment: Couldn't you, you know, *rephrase* that question?

Comment: You could also go for electorate. Takes just a bit over two weeks.

Comment: @slhck Which other Gold badges are as accessible? There aren't that many: Let's not count Reversal, Legendary, Publicist (awarded twice at most)... that leaves three for questions (10k views, 100 upvotes and 100 favorites), editing 500 posts (tags don't count), outscoring an accepted 10+ score answer by x2, 600 votes (the only other accessible one), answer with 100+ upvotes (only *very* few topics qualify), Unsung Hero, and Fanatic. Only *four* of these badges were awarded 20+ times each: 600 votes, 10k+ views, 100 days in a row, and 100+ score on answers.

Comment: @Daniel All I was trying to say is that people shouldn't care so much.  At least I wouldn't, not to that extent that I'd cheat. But that's just my 2 cents, because I'd get rid of some of those badges anyway.

Comment: How is "How can I automate opening a particular URL in a browser once or twice a day" off-topic on SU?

Comment: In the end it was just some kind of Joke, Daniel :)
I could put it in your terms and get an answer easily or just google it for myself.
I just felt like experimenting how a technical community would react to a spiky question :)
I am glad to read a comment like yours :)

Comment: @Pitto If you'd put it that way, it wouldn't have been migrated I guess. Either it's a honest question *or* it's a joke ;)

Comment: So you were just trying to start trouble... WHY????

Comment: What's the trouble??
It is a technical question, in the end.
Can anyone be so kind to show me any kind of rule that is against this?
In the end the whole point of the marvellous stackoverflow q/a system is that it gets better and improves itself using human minds.
I just found out a bug? Or it is a function we didn't think of?
It's just part of the concept, I think :)
You can get in the electorate cheating: it's a fact.
Should this kind of cheat be avoided or anyone SO constant to prepare this kind of solution should be in the electorate?
That's my question, if you read it :)

Comment: @slhck I just wanted to see what could happen. I just love the way superuser (and other sites) auto-patchfix-correct themself.
It's the best I've ever seen in human democracy.
It's pure meritocracy, in the end.
I was almost near to get the force-close on superuser.com (4 votes) so I thought to delete the question.
At the same time you migrated it and people here seemed to understand more.
It's a discussion: you got it before me :)

Comment: Mentioning @Kyle... @Pitto You *could* have made it a proper technical question without mentioning that you want to cheat on SU. This just isn't something we encourage here altogether, and I guess you already anticipated it ;) If you think the badges system is flawed, go to meta.SO and start a discussion or feature-request. That would be the best way to go about it.

Comment: You're right, mate.
But I discovered meta just when you transferred me :)
I simply can't embrace the whole stackexchange world :O

Comment: The question would be: "For superuser.com is a brainy thief valuable as a constant contributor"?
Being a scientific place where result is what counts (correct answer to correct question) I'd expect a "Yes".
But I'm just here to read what people think about it.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the question. However that comment where you claim it is "some kind of joke" and "I just felt like experimenting how a technical community would react to a spiky question" then you obviously know better and simply could have asked "how to refresh a browser once every 24 hours?" inexcusable, you were just trying to get a rise out of people and that is wrong... Then when your confronted by someone reasonable like @daniel you just back off and exclaim that you could find the answer easily on Google. In my eyes your nothing more then a troll...

Comment: If you take it this way you should just stop feeding me.
I didn't want to start a flame but just a discussion.
That's why I deleted the question on superuser.com when I understood that it was going to be a flame.
I've found the question migrated here _after_ I've deleted it.

Comment: Fair enough just calling it like I see it...

Comment: @Pitto deleted? it's [still around](http://superuser.com/questions/292418/how-can-i-become-fanatic-and-earn-gold-medal-on-superuser-com-cheating?noredirect=1)

Comment: I've deleted it!
Or, at least, I've clicked on delete.
Probably that was later than its migration.
Anyhow I'll do it now because it's becoming not so funny / interesting as I thouhgt.

Comment: "Sorry this question has answers and cannot be deleted" my precious feeder.

Comment: Flag it... by the way just trying to help at this point...

Comment: How about we disarm the question a bit and move this thing back to SU?

Comment: @Daniel No objections to that. We should look for duplicates though, I just found [a possible one](http://superuser.com/questions/216433/hit-a-website-every-x-minutes), but it could be more general, including cookies etc.

Comment: @slhck Not a duplicate. Doing real page views like in a browser are much more involved than a single HTTP request, e.g. using the SE login with HTML5 web database/local storage/whatever the hell they use, loading the resources included with the page, etc.

Comment: @Daniel - cleaned up and reopened on [Super User](http://superuser.com/q/292418/4377)

Comment: I've flagged it, tried to close it but no luck.

Comment: Not a bad idea! +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make it your homepage, that way you don't forget to contribute.

Comment: This still requires active use of the same computer every day (think about vacations, travel), or, on the other end of the spectrum, it requires your browser to actually be closed at least once a day.

Comment: @Daniel  Aaah, you see, not having a life, I take my notebook just about everywhere, so 100 days is easily achievable.

Comment: With 265 consecutive days, I can relate ;)

Comment: I need 30 more days to get my year-long-consecutive visited streak.  @DanielBeck

Comment: @Sathya So you'd support any feature requests for a 365-day platinum "Insanity" badge? ;)

Comment: @Daniel Would support it any time! ;)

Answer (score 4):

This question seems to be asking how to "cheat" the SuperUser.com system.  It's certainly not appropriate here, and I suspect that it wouldn't be very well received in "meta" either given the nature of what's being asked.

This question should be closed as it's not genuinely helpful to the majority of visitors.

Comment: It's just some kind of "joke" but also a technical question.

Comment: @Pitto:  In that case, pre-fixing the title with "Humour:" probably would have prevented [at least] some of the _down votes_ that are appearing.  Unfortunately there are a number of people who regularly ask questions about **dark hacking** in all sorts of forums, IRC channels, etc., only to be greeted with discouragement (for good reason), and so I'm assuming this may be one of the reasons your question has received some negative reactions.  Dark Hacking not encouraged in online communities like SuperUser.com because the primary focus is on helping people solve problems.

Answer (score 3):

Use Safari's "Top Sites" feature, they are periodically reloaded I believe (I have way too much recorded attendance on SO and no other explanation). Other browsers might have a similar feature, and Opera can automatically reload web pages.

Comment: The current version of Opera can automatically reload pages (right-click on the web page, then click on the "Reload Every" sub-menu).