# Question migrated to Meta.SuperUser has incorrect URL in the Global Inbox permalink

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, globalinbox

Soon as a question is posted on meta, diamond mods get a notification of that in their inbox.

I just [migrated a question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2657/how-can-i-become-fanatic-and-earn-gold-medal-on-superuser-com-cheating) from superuser.com to meta.superuser.com and found that the question permalink is incorrect and thereby leads to a 404 page.

This is the URL in the GlobalInbox

`https://meta.superuser.com/questions/0/how-can-i-become-fanatic-and-earn-gold-medal-on-superuser-com-cheating`

while it should have been

`https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2657/how-can-i-become-fanatic-and-earn-gold-medal-on-superuser-com-cheating`

Comment: Isn't Meta.SO more appropriate for software issues?

Comment: @DanielBeck - Robert Cartaino has mentioned `Network-related questions are okay hosted on your meta site. Please pass that on to your community when you see users shutting down discussions with "This should be asked on meta.SO."`

Comment: The team is going to slap us if we ever dare say that again @Daniel!

Comment: hehe :) true that @IvoFlipse

Comment: @Ivo I don't have a ♦, you don't even [trust me](http://superuser.com/privileges/trusted-user) so I'm allowed to be as wrong as I want ;) But still, good to know.

Comment: @DanielBeck, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on/89232#89232

Comment: Ironically @Rebecca, we have to read about this on... MSO

Comment: @IvoFlipse, oy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recent refactor of migrations (which are now much less terrible, at least code wise, now) introduced this bug.  Basically, notifying mods of posts before they're inserted into database; in which case `Post.Id = default(int) = 0`.

A fix for this has been checked in, and will go out with the build later today.