# Is "noise or pointless" coming back?

Tags: support, close-reasons

I noticed that many questions closed as noise or pointless were later changed to not constructive; however, today I saw a question with this old status again:

[image]

Is this intended, or is it a bug?

Comment: That was back in Jan, 2012... Two years ago

Comment: Having said that, I think it would be a great close reason to bring back :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions closed with a particular reason will still show that reason even if it's no longer an option today.

"Noise or pointless" will not be coming back.

Comment: Yeah, but previously, questions originally closed as noise or pointless would later show as being closed as not constructive. My question was asking if questions closed with this reason now show up as the actual reason instead of as not constructive.

Comment: Point out two examples with links

Comment: One: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2657/how-can-i-become-fanatic-and-earn-gold-medal-on-superuser-com-cheating Other: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4068/question-migrated-but-my-flag-was-declined

Comment: "noise or pointless" was only ever an option for meta questions

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67393/close-reasons-on-meta-se-sites-should-be-consistent-with-mso/95188#95188

Comment: So you want them to go back and fix those few that are showing an old close reason?

Comment: No. I am just curious why they decided to show the original close reason now instead of showing them as "not constructive" as before.

Comment: For the most part it's just how the close reason was written against the question